# MPAndroidChart - how to create vertical y-axis labels at bottom of the chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

how to create vertical y-axis labels at bottom of the chart? 
this is what my current chart looks like: https://db.tt/F5M3iAPQ
this is what I want: https://db.tt/mCpy6YuP

I already posted this issue on the author's github, issue #209

Thanks

Comment: 8 months later... still looking for this. Any luck?

Comment: @fahmy , you can see at https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/209 , the library author himself says this feature is not supported on mpandroidchart. so you must create the feature yourself.

Comment: @Dika do you found any way to solve this???